# Hash with default value that depends on the key

Tags: ruby, hash, default

I have a string and a hash with a default value of `"*"`:

```
my_string = "a b c d"
my_hash = Hash.new("*")
my_hash["a"] = 1
my_hash["b"] = 2
```

Then I do

```
new_string = my_string.gsub(/[abcd]/, my_hash)
# => "1 2 * *"
```

How can I make `new_string` also include the string that couldn't be found in `my_hash` and have

```
new_string # => "1 2 *c *d"
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "c" in my regex. I edited and clarified my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_hash = Hash.new{|_, k| "*#{k}"}
my_hash["a"] = 1
my_hash["b"] = 2
my_string.gsub(/[abcd]/, my_hash)
# => "1 2 *c *d"
```

Comment: Thanks, sawa! We posted an answer at the same time. Can you tell me what the underscore in Hash.new means?

Comment: It is a convention to represent a variable that is not used. The difference between your answer and mine is that yours assigns a new key-value each time a new key is called.

Comment: Alternatively, `my_hash = { "a"=>1, "b"=>2 }.tap { |h| h.default_proc = ->(_, k){ "*#{k}" }  } #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}; my_hash["a"] #=> 1; my_hash["c"] #=> "*c"`.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I figured it out.

Instead of setting my default value for my_hash as "*" using

```
my_hash = Hash.new("*")
```

I do

```
my_hash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = "*" + k}
```

So now, if the string to be replaced is found but has no corresponding key in my_hash ("c" and "d" in this case), I replace it with the default my_hash value and itself.

Now new_string is

```
"1 2 *c *d"
```